# What is the equivalent word for embed (a video) and insert (text) for a picture?

Tags: word-request

You embed a video and insert text. What do you do with pictures?

I suppose you can use more general terms like 'include' or 'add', but I want to know if there is a specific verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more about IT terminology than it is about English language. As I understand it, the reason that "embed" is used with a video in a webpage is that, for a video to *play* from a website, the *video player* must be able to run in the page. You can *insert* a link to a video on a page which will allow people to download it, or even play/stream it in using a native player - but for it to play in the original page as intended, it must be *embedded*.

Really then, "insert" (or "import") can be used for pretty much anything that you might bring into a document, or a webpage at the design stage. It only really becomes a different verb if the terminology demands it.

Comment: Lexico says "text only" (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/insert)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev But that dictionary example is not specific to computing. You could insert text into a piece of handwriting by rewriting it. Terminology is often limited to a particular technical application in a subject of study or profession. As such, it is not always included in dictionaries.